# Google Сhrome new Secure Preferences, how mod preferences now?

Tags: google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extensions, json

In new Сhrome version 37.0.2062.120 m appeared new Secure Preferences file, how make modification preferences now?

Secure Preferences file:

```
{
"extensions": {
"settings": {
}
},
"protection": {
"macs": {
"browser": {
"show_home_button": "6F07A285FE2C96A4DFF2CA4CA5783179E9C811CBC11DCDDBFB134EDCF6A3744C"
},
"extensions": {
"aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc": "11D619FC1E8DD99DF100E17B1D95F64D3C46BF6A5538D6031C80608720D9BDAD",
}
}
}
}
```

What is this protect mac code "11D619FC1E8DD99DF100E17B1D95F64D3C46BF6A5538D6031C80608720D9BDAD"? Is it hash code? How correct generate this code?

Comment: What preferences do you want to change exactly?

Comment: Add extensions settings in (->"extensions"->"settings") and add protect mac code (->"protection"->"macs"->"extensions") for successful install my extension.

Comment: My guess is that they had to do this _precisely_ to avoid random developers force-installing their extensions. (Much like Mozilla had, two years ago. And even Internet Explorer recently.)

Comment: grawity, your comment it's not answer..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

11D619FC1E8DD99DF100E17B1D95F64D3C46BF6A5538D6031C80608720D9BDAD is a lattice based hash called SWIFFT. You can easily revert it and create your own by doing a fast fourier transform on it, find the pointwise product of the range when you interpret the extension id as a multiple-precision integer.

I wrote a tool to do this, but it requires the use of the decoherence library, which is propietary, and you wouldn't be able to use it. But if you want, I can create another hash for your extension id if you post it here.

Comment: While this is interesting, do you have any pointers to Chrome documentation and/or source code where SWIFFT is being used or that it's reversible, or anything in general for everyone else to verify that this is an actual answer rather than a vaguely-crypto-sounding jumble of words?

Comment: This answer is nonsense. The actual implementation doesn't involve SWIFFT at all. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/trunk/chrome/browser/prefs/pref_hash_calculator.cc And in any case, the steps described wouldn't make sense even if SWIFFT was in the picture.

Comment: @duskwuff - How would we be able to edit Secure Prefs now? And how to calculate the Hash manually?

Comment: @AlexS You don't. This mechanism is in place specifically to prevent external programs from tampering with browser settings. If you want to edit these settings, you do it through the Chrome user interface.

Comment: @duskwuff So, how can I go about doing this? http://superuser.com/questions/951095/understand-structure-of-chrome-user-profile-data-to-transfer-to-new-pc-os-avo

Comment: @duskwuff - 1. I am guessing 'some' Extensions & Cookies related information gets mapped into files: Preferences & Secure Preferences?? Is it the case now with Chrome 44? 
2. Is there anyway to edit the files to match the E & Cs? 
3. Anyway to rewrite them?

Comment: @duskwuff - Can you or someone post an executable solution that allows someone to create and use such Hashes?

Comment: @AlexS No. The point of the whole thing is to prevent that.

Comment: @duskwuff - When Chrome tends to Swallow up & mess someones User Profile and someone needs to piece together parts of it, it would really help. http://superuser.com/questions/951095/understand-structure-of-chrome-user-profile-data-to-transfer-to-new-pc-os-avo